# #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an error when trying to run this query:

```
UPDATE tbl1, tbl2 SET `tb1`.field=SUM(tbl2.grade) WHERE tbl2.word=tbl1.word
```

This is the error: `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

I basically trying to get the sum of a field from tbl2 and insert it into tbl1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want to do is via a subquery:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET tbl1.field=
    (SELECT SUM(tbl2.grade) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.word=tbl1.word)
```

You're selecting multiple values from tbl2 and want the sum of them for each entry in tbl1.

Answer (score 4):

Join against a subquery that calculates the total grade for every word.

```
UPDATE  tbl1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  word, SUM(grade) totalGrade
            FROM    tbl2
            GROUP   BY word
        ) b ON a.word = b.word
SET     a.field = b.totalGrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET `tbl1`.field = (
    SELECT SUM(tbl2.grade)
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.word = tbl1.word
    );
```